# How do I use FastAPI's "response_model_exclude_none" as a variable option

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

In FastApi you can set `response_model_exclude_none=True` to exclude fields with value `None`. As an example, I could set up an endpoint like so:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel

class TestModel(BaseModel):
  model_option: str

router = APIRouter(prefix="/hello", tags=["test"])
@router.get(
    "/world",
    response_model=TestModel,
    response_model_exclude_none=True,
)
def return_model(model_option: str):
  return TestModel(model_option=model_option)
```

As a user, the arguments I can pass are exclusively in the `return_model` function. Is there a way to allow the user to also pass the `response_model_exclude_none` argument in the `router.get()` decorator so that they can decide whether or not they want to exclude `None` values or not?

Comment: Since you can't adjust the decorator parameters on a per-request basis, you can use `return TestModel(...).dict(exclude_none=<your value>)` to explicitly convert the pydantic model in a way you find suitable. This is what happens behind the scenes when you return the model to FastAPI: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict - I'm not aware of (and didn't find) any way to do it directly as a parameter to `JSONResponse` for example.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am aware of simply coverting ``TestModel`` in the ``return_model`` function itself. I was wondering if it's possible to do it in the decorator. But if not, no biggy.

Comment: It won't, since the input to the decorator isn't evaluated each time the decorator is called, it runs once and returns the new, wrapped function (which is how decorators work in Python - there might be some magic to handle that, but I'm not aware of any).